# A Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException occurs when rendering many CheckBoxes

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, winui-3

I'm working on WinUI3. An UnhandledException occurs when the code below is executed and CheckBoxes are rendered.

```
public List<int> Collection { get; set; }

public ViewModelConstructor()
{
    Collection = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Collection.Add(0);
    }
}
```

```
<ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Collection}">
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:Int32">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
            <CheckBox/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsRepeater>
```

```
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
};

// e.Message: "Failed to assign to property 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.AnimatedIcon.Source'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]"
// e.Exception.Message: "XAML parsing failed."
// typeof(e.Exception): Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyTRV.png)

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Gvc.png)

It works normally when modified like the code below.

```
public ViewModelConstructor()
{
    Collection = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        Collection.Add(0);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, changing CheckBox to Button will work normally.

```
<ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Collection}">
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:Int32">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsRepeater>
```

I've tried many things and guessed it, it seems to happen when there are many CheckBoxes.

Is there any issue or solution related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/pull/5171), which is supposed to be fixed.

**TLTR**: This seems to be an issue only for `CheckBoxes` and there seems to be no workaround for the moment. So, think again if this is what you really need.

I tried a few things and this is what I found (at least in my laptop):

`CheckBoxes`:

- The max number you can instantiate in the MainWindow. (Haven't tried in`Pages`.):

  - WinAppSDK v1.1: 286 items
  - WinAppSDK v1.2: 563 items
- You get the exception even if you separate the `CheckBoxes` in different `Grids`. (Haven't tried different `Pages`.)

`Buttons`, `ToggleButtons`, even `Expanders`:

- You can instantiate more than 10,000 items without getting the exception.

Comment: Personally, I don't think this is a critical issue but I guess it's worth posting an issue in the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) so the team knows about this behavior. Let me know if you need me to do it for you.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could do that.

Comment: Posted an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8110). But I wouldn't expect this to be processed in a short time.

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8110#issuecomment-1853903040) closed. According to the WinUI 3 team, updating to v1.4 or later should fix the it.